# Set model of all elements to param value?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, param, setvalue

I really need some assistance with this code.
I'm unsure how exactly to do part 3. It states to use model to set the value, but its been pretty much trial and error without progress.

```
      setSize( 500,400 );

      carList = new ArrayList<Auto>( );

      ad = new AutoDisplay( carList );
      setVisible( true );
      ad.setEraseColor( getBackground( ) );
      // fill carList with several cars
      fillWithCars( );
   }

   // ***** 1.  This method has been coded as an example
   /** Fills the carList with hard-coded Auto objects
   *    The instance variable carList is the ArrayList
   *    to be filled with Auto objects
   */
   public void fillWithCars()
   {
     // clear carList before adding cars
     carList.clear();
     // Reset the number of Autos to 0
     // This is needed so that the animation feedback works correctly
     Auto.clearNumberAutos();

     Auto car1 = new Auto("BMW", 0, 0.0);
     Auto car2 = new Auto("Ferrari", 100, 500.0);
     Auto car3 = new Auto("Jeep", 1000, 90.0);
     Auto car4 = new Auto("Ferrari", 10, 3.0);
     Auto car5 = new Auto("BMW", 4000, 200.0);
     Auto car6 = new Auto("Ferrari", 1000, 50.0);

     carList.add(car1);
     carList.add(car2);
     carList.add(car3);
     carList.add(car4);
     carList.add(car5);
     carList.add(car6);
     animate();
   }

   // ***** 2.  Student writes this method
   /**  Prints carList to console, elements are separated by a space
   *    The instance variable carList is the ArrayList to be printed
   */
   public void printAutoList()
   {
     // Note:  To animate the algorithm, put this method call as the
     // last element in your for loop
     //    animate(car);
     //  where car is the variable name for the current Auto object
     //  as you loop through the ArrayList object
     // Part 2 student code starts here:
System.out.println(carList);
Auto car;
for (int i = 0; i < carList.size();i++)
{
    car=carList.get(i);
    animate(car);
}
     // Part 2 student code ends here.
   }

   // ***** 3.  Student writes this method
   /** Sets the model of all the elements in carList to parameter value
   *    The instance variable carList is the ArrayList to be modified
   *  @param model the model to assign to all Auto objects in carList
   */
   public void setModelValues(String model)
   {
     // Note:  To animate the algorithm, put this method call as the
     // last statement in your for loop
     //    animate(car);
     //  where car is the variable name for the current Auto object
     //  as you loop through the ArrayList object
     // Part 3 student code starts here:
       for (Auto car: carList)
       {
        carList.add(carList.get(car).toString());  
        System.out.println(model.toString(odel.toArray()));
         animate(car);
       }
     // Part 3 student code ends here.
   }

   // ***** 4.  Student writes this method
   /** Finds maximum number of miles driven
   *   Instance variable carList is the ArrayList to search
   *  @return the maximum miles driven by all the Auto objects
   */
   public int findMaximumMilesDriven()
   {
     // Note:  To animate the algorithm, put this method call as the
     // last statement in your for loop
     //    animate(car, maximum);
     //  where car is the variable name for the current Auto object
     //  and maximum is the int variable storing the current maximum
     //  number of miles for all Auto elements you have already tested
     //  as you loop through the ArrayList object
     // Part 4 student code starts here:



     return 0; // replace this statement with your return statement

     // Part 4 student code ends here.
   }


   // ***** 5.  Student writes this method
   /** Finds number of times parameter model is found in the carList
   *   Instance variable carList is the ArrayList in which we search
   *  @param model  the model to count
   *  @return   the number of times model was found
   */
   public int countFound(String model)
   {
     // Note:  To animate the algorithm, put this method call as the
     // last statement in your for loop
     //    animate(car, num);
     //  where car is the variable name for the current Auto object
     //  and num is the int variable storing the current number of
     //  Auto elements whose model is equal to the method's parameter
     //  as you loop through the ArrayList object
     // Part 5 student code starts here:



     return 0; // replace this statement with your return statement

     // Part 5 student code ends here.
   }

   public void startActivity( int act )
   {
      ad.setActivity( act );
      boolean goodInput = false;
      String answer = "";
      String message = "";
      switch( act )
      {
       case  0:
        fillWithCars( );
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "carList filled with new values" );
          break;

       case  1:
        printAutoList( );
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "carList printed" );
          break;

       case  2:
        answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Enter a car model" );
          if (answer != null )
          {
           ad.setSearchModel( answer );
           setModelValues( answer );
           if ( ad.getCurrentModelValuesSet( ) )
             message = "\nYour result is correct";
           else
             message = "\nYour result is not correct";
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "car models set to " + answer + message );
          }
          break;

      case 3:
       int a = findMaximumMilesDriven( );
         if ( a == ad.getCurrentMaximumMilesDriven( ) )
          message = "\nYour result is correct";
         else
          message = "\nYour result is not correct";
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "The maximum number of miles driven is " + a + message );
         break;

      case  4:
       answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Enter a car model" );
         if ( answer != null )
         {
          ad.setSearchModel( answer );
          int frequency = countFound( answer );
          if ( frequency == ad.getCurrentCountModelFound( ) )
           message = "\nYour result is correct";
          else
           message = "\nYour result is not correct";
          if ( frequency > 1 )
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, answer + " found " + frequency + " times" + message );
          else if ( frequency == 1 )
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, answer + " found " + frequency + " time" + message );
          else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, answer + " not found" + message );
        }
        break;
      }
      enableButtons( );
   }

   public static Auto getCurrent( )
   {
    return current;
   }

   public static ArrayList getCarList( )
   {
    return carList;
   }

   private void animate( Auto au )
   {
    if ( ad.getActivity( ) == 1 || ad.getActivity( ) == 2 )
    {
     try
     {
      current = au;
      ad.setCarList( carList );
      ad.setCurrentAuto( au );
      ad.setCurrentIndex( au.getIndex( ) );
      repaint( );
      Thread.sleep( 4000 );
     }
     catch ( InterruptedException e )
     {
      System.out.println( "IE Exception " + e.getMessage( ) );
      System.out.println( e.toString( ) );
     }
    }
    else
    {
      // call to animate has wrong number of arguments
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong number of arguments to animate method" );
      System.exit( 1 );
    }
   }

   private void animate( Auto au, int studentResult )
   {
    if ( ad.getActivity( ) == 3 || ad.getActivity( ) == 4 )
    {
     try
     {
      current = au;
      ad.setCarList( carList );
      ad.setCurrentAuto( au );
      ad.setCurrentIndex( au.getIndex( ) );
      ad.setStudentResult( studentResult );
      repaint( );
      Thread.sleep( 4000 );
     }
     catch ( InterruptedException e )
     {
      System.out.println( "IE Exception " + e.getMessage( ) );
      System.out.println( e.toString( ) );
     }
    }
    else
    {
      // call to animate has wrong number of arguments
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong number of arguments to animate method" );
      System.exit( 1 );
    }
   }

   private void animate( )
   {
    if ( ad.getActivity( ) == 0 )
    {
     try
     {
      ad.setCarList( carList );
      repaint( );
      Thread.sleep( 4000 );
     }
     catch ( InterruptedException e )
     {
      System.out.println( "IE Exception " + e.getMessage( ) );
      System.out.println( e.toString( ) );
     }
    }
    else
    {
      // call to animate has wrong number of arguments
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong number of arguments to animate method" );
      System.exit( 1 );
    }
   }

   public void paint( Graphics g )
   {
     if ( ( ( current != null ) || firstTime ) && ( ad.getActivity( ) != 0 ) )
     {
       super.paint( g );
       if ( ad.getCurrentAuto( ) != null )
           ad.updateAutoDisplay( current, g );
       firstTime = false;
     }
     else if ( ad.getActivity( ) == 0 )
     {
       super.paint( g );
       ad.updateAutoDisplay( g );
     }
   }

   public static void main( String [] args )
   {
      app = new ArrayListPractice( );
      app.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
   }

   public void disableButtons( )
   {
     fillValues.setEnabled( false );
     printAutoList.setEnabled( false );
     setValues.setEnabled( false );
     countFrequency.setEnabled( false );
     findMaximum.setEnabled( false );
   }

   public void enableButtons( )
   {
     fillValues.setEnabled( true );
     printAutoList.setEnabled( true );
     setValues.setEnabled( true );
     countFrequency.setEnabled( true );
     findMaximum.setEnabled( true );
   }

   private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
   {
    private boolean on = true;
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
      printAutoListT t = new printAutoListT( app );

      if ( e.getSource( ) == fillValues )
      {
        disableButtons( );
        fillValues.requestFocus( );
        ad.setActivity( 0 );
        t.start( );
      }
      else if ( e.getSource( ) == printAutoList )
      {
        disableButtons( );
        printAutoList.requestFocus( );
        ad.setActivity( 1 );
        t.start( );
      }
      else if ( e.getSource( ) == setValues )
      {
        disableButtons( );
        setValues.requestFocus( );
        ad.setActivity( 2 );
        t.start( );
      }
      else if ( e.getSource( ) == findMaximum )
      {
        disableButtons( );
        findMaximum.requestFocus( );
        ad.setActivity( 3 );
        t.start( );
      }
      else if ( e.getSource( ) == countFrequency )
      {
        disableButtons( );
        countFrequency.requestFocus( );
        ad.setActivity( 4 );
        t.start( );
      }
    }
  }

  private class printAutoListT extends Thread
  {
     ArrayList<Auto> arr;
     ArrayListPractice s1;
     public printAutoListT ( ArrayListPractice s )
     {
      arr = ArrayListPractice.carList;
      s1 = s;
     }
     public void run( )
     {
      startActivity( ad.getActivity( ) );
     }
  }
}
```

Auto class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Auto
{
    // Static instance variable - number of Auto objects references created
    private static int numberAutos = 0;
    // Instance variables
    private String model;           //  model of auto
    private int milesDriven;       //  number of miles driven
    private double gallonsOfGas;   //  number of gallons of gas
    private int index;        //  car number

    // Default constructor:
    //  Initializes model to a blank String
    //  milesDriven are autoinitialized to 0, gallonsOfGas to 0.0
    public Auto( )
    {
      model = "";
      index = numberAutos;
      numberAutos++;
    }

    // Overloaded constructor:
    // Allows client to set beginning values for
    //   model, milesDriven, and gallonsOfGas.
    //   Calls mutator methods to validate new values.
    public Auto( String startModel,
                 int startMilesDriven,
                 double startGallonsOfGas )
    {
      model = startModel;
      setMilesDriven( startMilesDriven );
      setGallonsOfGas( startGallonsOfGas );
      index = numberAutos;
      numberAutos++;
    }

    // Accessor method:
    // Returns current value of index
    public int getIndex( )
    {
      return index;
    }

    // Accessor method:
    // Returns current value of model
    public String getModel( )
    {
      return model;
    }

    // Accessor method:
    // Returns current value of milesDriven
    public int getMilesDriven( )
    {
      return milesDriven;
    }

    // Accessor method:
    //  Returns current value of gallonsOfGas
    public double getGallonsOfGas( )
    {
      return gallonsOfGas;
    }

    // Mutator method:
    // Allows client to set model
    public void setModel( String newModel )
    {
      model = newModel;
    }

    // Mutator method:
    // Allows client to set value of milesDriven
    // prints an error message if new value is less than 0
    public void setMilesDriven( int newMilesDriven )
    {
      if ( newMilesDriven >= 0 )
         milesDriven = newMilesDriven;
      else
      {
         System.err.println( "Miles driven must be at least 0." );
         System.err.println( "Value not changed." );
      }
    }

    // Mutator method:
    // Allows client to set value of gallonsOfGas;
    // prints an error message if new value is less than 0.0
    public void setGallonsOfGas( double newGallonsOfGas )
    {
      if ( newGallonsOfGas >= 0.0 )
         gallonsOfGas = newGallonsOfGas;
      else
      {
         System.err.println( "Gallons of gas must be at least 0." );
         System.err.println( "Value not changed." );
      }
    }

    // Mutator method
    // Allows client to add miles driven and gallons of gas used
    //  to current values;
    // prints error messages if new values are less than 0
    public void addMileage( int newMilesDriven,
                            double newGallonsOfGas )
    {
      if ( newMilesDriven < 0 )
      {
         System.err.println( "Miles driven must be at least 0." );
         System.err.println( "Value not changed" );
         return;   // do not continue executing method
      }

      if ( newGallonsOfGas < 0.0 )
      {
         System.err.println( "Gallons of gas must positive." );
         System.err.println( "Value not changed" );
         return;  // do not continue executing method
      }

      // ok to change values
      milesDriven += newMilesDriven;  // add newMilesDriven
      gallonsOfGas += newGallonsOfGas; // add newGallonsOfGas
    }

    // Calculates mileage as miles per gallon.
    //  If no gallons of gas have been used, returns 0.0;
    //  Otherwise, returns miles per gallon
    //        as milesDriven / gallonsOfGas
    public double calculateMilesPerGallon( )
    {
      if ( gallonsOfGas != 0.0 )
         return milesDriven / gallonsOfGas;
      else
         return 0.0;
    }

    public static void clearNumberAutos( )
    {
        numberAutos = 0;
    }

    public String toString( )
    {
      DecimalFormat gallonsFormat = new DecimalFormat( "##.0" );
      return "Model: " + model
           + " Miles driven: " + milesDriven
           + " Gallons of gas: "
           + gallonsFormat.format( gallonsOfGas );
    }

    public void draw( Graphics g, int startX, int endX, int y)
    {}

     } // end Auto class definition
```

Any assistance would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You don't show the `Auto` class, but perhaps it has a method, `setModel(String model)` ?

Comment: yes it does. i apologize im new so i didnt know how to post it 
public void setModel( String newModel )
    {
      model = newModel;
    }